# Hilbert space Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $K ⊂H$ be a nonempty closed convex set, $H$ Hilbert. Let $f ∈H$ and let $u=P_Kf$. Prove that
$$||v − u||^2 ≤ ||v − f ||^2 − ||u − f ||^2, ∀v ∈ K$$

I've tried to use the parallelogram identity and the relation $||u-v||^2=||u||^2+||v||^2-2<u,v>$ without any success.

Do you have any hint?

This is what I have done, but it does not work!

$\forall v,u\in H$ it holds: $||v+u||^2=||u||^2+||v||^2+2<u,v>$ (*),

then:

$||v-u||^2=||v-f+f-u||^2=$

$=||(v-f)+(f-u)||^2=^{(*)}$

$=||u-f||^2+||v-f||^2+2<v-f,f-u>$

$=||u-f||^2+||v-f||^2-2<f-v,f-u>$

but now?

Comment: Use that $\langle f- P_K f, v -P_K f \rangle \leq 0$, which is a property of the orthogonal projection. Start from the left hand side and use the parallelogram identity to obtain your result.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 thank you very much!

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I've edited the question, but still it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall v,u\in H$ it holds: $||v+u||^2=||u||^2+||v||^2+2<u,v>$ (*),

then:

$||v-u||^2=||v-f+f-u||^2=$

$=||(v-f)+(f-u)||^2=^{(*)}$

$=||u-f||^2+||v-f||^2+2<v-f,f-u>=$(1)

Now we have: $<v-f,f-u>=<v-u+u-f,f-u>=<v-u,f-u>-||u-f||^2$, therefore:

(1)$=||u-f||^2+||v-f||^2+2(<v-u,f-u>-||u-f||^2)=$

$=||v-f||^2-||u-f||^2+2<v-u,f-u>.$

To summarise:

$$||v-u||^2=||v-f||^2-||u-f||^2+2<v-u,f-u>$$

Since $u=P_Kf$ it holds: $⟨f−u,v−u⟩≤0, \forall v\in H$,
it is now straightforward to see that:

$||v-u||^2\leq ||u-f||^2+||v-f||^2.$

Comment: where is the plus comming from?

Answer (score 1):

Let me also give a hint on how to start:

$$\|v -P_K f \|^2 = \langle v -f +f -P_K f, v- P_K f\rangle = \langle v -f, v - P_K f\rangle + \langle f -P_K f, v - P_K f\rangle$$

With my hint, i.e. $\langle f -P_K f, v -P_K f\rangle\leq 0$ (at least in a real Hilbert-space, otherwise this only holds for the real part of the expression) applied to the second term  of the rhs and with your parallelogramm identity applied to the first term of the rhs, we obtain

$$\|v -P_K f \|^2 \leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\|v-f\|^2 + \|v -P_K f\|^2 -\|f-P_Kf\|^2 \right)$$
Multiply by $2$ and subtract the term $\|v-P_K f\|^2$ to complete the proof.

Comment: I can not, I feel so retarded:
$=<v-f,v-u+f-f>+<f-u,v-u+f-f>=

||v-f||^2+<v-f,f-u>+||u-f||^2+<f-u,v-f>= ||v-f||^2+||u-f||^2+2<v-f,f-v>$

I get exactly the same as above

Comment: Use my first hint on the last term and your parallelogram identity on the first. Note that your parallelogram identity yields an expression for the scalar product. Does this help?

Comment: Sorry man, I appreciate a lot what you are doing for me, but I really do not see it. Maybe it is because it is since this morning I am on this, I convinced myself I can't do it. May you please show me the result?